# Organizing Eclipse Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

I love being organized, and I hate having all my java projects in eclipse right in the workspace. It makes it very cluttered, and I wanted a more organized approach, where I have folders in my workspace for different kinds of projects. However, folders can only be added into other folders, and not the workspace itself. Also, I wanted a way to be able to put classes into just any folder, and not just the src folder in a project. I love eclipse, but I really want the way to organize my programs to be a little more flexible. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Not sure what kind of "organization" you're looking for. Any folder can be a source folder, although I wouldn't recommend it. What do you mean by "organize your programs to be more flexible"? Flexible in what way? Not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think what is organized to 1 person is not the same for another. I have found some of these techniques helpful maybe they will help you

- Group projects to working sets so you do not see the full workspace
- You can keep sources in different folders add those source folders in the build path
- Use tools like Collabnet that integrates with your version control repository and issue management systems like JIRA and at given point in time you can view only the files that are relevant to the issue you are working with.

  - Know your keyboard shortcuts very well

Comment: I agree with this answer. At first I disliked how Eclipse puts everything in one workspace, and switching workspace is very slow and annoying (losing all my preferences!!)  HOWEVER, now that I have learned to use WORKING SETS, I am mostly happy. I can quickly change from one set of projects to another. Unfortunately it is still not possible to have two versions of code in the same workspace (for instance, both dev and release).

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand, you are formulating two expectations:

1. Have a clear directory structure for your projects, independent from the IDE;
2. Have a clear workspace organization, which reflects the underlying structure of your projects.

There is something you did not mention, which is the build facility for your project. I guess you are compiling and running your projects from within Eclipse? If not, or if you are willing to compile, test, deploy and run your project besides your Eclipse IDE, you can have a look to full-featured tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

The point is that even if you do not want to build your project outside of the IDE, this tool will save you so much time that it is even worth to use it only to have a clear, proper, conventional and understandable directory structure as you seem to expect. On the other hand, the problem is that such a tool addresses issues that are far beyond your own requirements, which may render it overkill to use for the sole purpose exposed above.

Maven is a perfect tool for those who like to be organized. One of its core concept is *convention over configuration*.

This means, for instance, that if you follow Maven conventions for your projects, the simple command

```
 mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

will generate for each of your them a corresponding Eclipse project, which you will be able to configure, generate and clean from outside Eclipse.